# How to export/import cookies using Java + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a tool using Java + Selenium WebDriver and I run it every day. How can I export the cookies, histories... and import/reuse it for next execution like a normal browser.

Comment: Load the profile when you are loading the browser.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the profile information of the browser to the JSON file and later instantiate new browsers with the same profile.

**FirefoxProfile** class provides **toJson()** method to write profile information

**FirefoxProfile** class provides **fromJson()** method to retrieve profile information

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(
new File("src/test/resources/extensions/anyextenstion.file"));
String json = profile.toJson();
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(FirefoxProfile.fromJson(json));
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```